# WMI query returns "Generic Failure" exception for certain classes

Tags: permissions, powershell, remote, wmi

I am trying to query **Win32_USBHub** or **Win32_DiskDrive** on a remote server using PowerShell, but I am receiving the following error:

```
[PS]> Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_USBHub" -ComputerName MyServer -Credential $Cred | Select -First 1

Get-WmiObject : Generic failure 
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_USBHub" -ComputerName MyServer -Credential $Cred | S ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

The same command works correctly when I use different credentials (i.e. an account that is a full Administrator of the remote host). I do *not* want to have to elevate `$cred` to be an Administrator though.

The `$cred` used is a member of the **Distributed COM Users** group on the remote machine and has **Remote Enable** rights set on the `\root` node in **WMI Control**, applied to **This namespace and subspaces**. Before doing that I was getting a simple "Access Denied" error.

The same command works correctly (i.e. does not throw an exception) when I query **Win32_Process** or **Win32_OperatingSystem** against that same remote host with the same credentials, proving that at least some remote WMI calls work successfully.

Can anyone suggest why I might be able to query some classes successfully and others not?

Comment: You have to trace the providers and resources they query.  Then analyze which resources require what permission levels.  Correlate them and ensure your user object has them.  It's a lot of work, but that's the process you use when avoiding elevation to admin.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure that would be possible, so I'll have more confidence digging through now. If you have any links I'd appreciate it. :-)